# Conditional statements in python with an iterative process

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am simulating the temperature of a material in various circumstances. I would like to produce a plot of temperature versus time, where all the temperature drops by an additional 5 degrees after a certain temperature and then the rate of temperature change is observed. Initially I had the following:

```
for i in range(1,len(t)):
    te[i] = te[i-1] + f(te[i-1])*dt
```

Which was used to plot a curve decreasing with time (t). I would like to produce two parts to the plot now. The x-values of my plot are t. The y-values are Te. I would like to decrease all Te values by an additional 5, after the time at which Te is less than 80. I usually use IDL so would say something along the lines of T where(t=80). This is what I have so far, obviously the syntax is completely incorrect, and the i values are indexes and not values of time.

```
t80 = t where Te <= 80.0

for i in range(1,t80):
    te[i] = te[i-1] + f(te[i-1])*dt 

for i in range(t80,len(t)):
    te3[i] = te3[i-1] + f(te3[i-1])*dt - 5
```

Does anyone know how I would define t80 in python?

Comment: Is your last formula correct? Not sure if you want the temperature to decrese by 5 degrees _once_ after `t80` or _in every step_ thereafter.

Comment: Also, one temperature drops below 80, will it stay below 80, and if not, what happens if it rises above 80 again (and drops below once more)?

Comment: Essentially I have a liquid which is hot and cooling down to the Temperature if it’s surroundings. I have defined a function which describes this behavior. After adding a cooler liquid, and the temperature then drops by 5 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, the temperature will decrease *once* by an additional 5 degrees when the temperature drops below 80 degrees. If this is correct, you could simply add an `if` condition to your `for` loop:

```
cooling_liquid_poured = False
for i in range(1,len(t)):
    te[i] = te[i-1] + f(te[i-1])*dt 
    if te[i] < 80 and not cooling_liquid_poured:
        te[i] -= 5
        cooling_liquid_poured = True
```

If instead the temperature should drop by an additional 5 degrees in *every* step after the liquid has been poured, just remove that variable and just check `if te[i] < 80`.